# R ddply, applying if and ifelse functions

Tags: r, plyr

I'm trying to apply a function to a dataframe using ddply from the plyr package, but I'm getting some results that I don't understand.  I have 3 questions about the
results

Given:

```
mydf<- data.frame(c(12,34,9,3,22,55),c(1,2,1,1,2,2)
                  , c(0,1,2,1,1,2))
colnames(mydf)[1] <- 'n'
colnames(mydf)[2] <- 'x'
colnames(mydf)[3] <- 'x1'
```

mydf looks like this:

```
   n x x1
1 12 1  0
2 34 2  1
3  9 1  2
4  3 1  1
5 22 2  1
6 55 2  2
```

#### Question #1

If I do:

```
k <- function(x) {
  mydf$z <- ifelse(x == 1, 0, mydf$n)
  return (mydf)
}
mydf <- ddply(mydf, c("x") , .fun = k, .inform = TRUE)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "z", value = structure(c(12, 34, 9,  : 
  replacement has 3 rows, data has 6
Error: with piece 1: 
   n x x1
1 12 1  0
2  9 1  2
3  3 1  1
```

I get this error regardless of whether I specify the variable to split by as c("x"), "x", or .(x). I don't understand why I'm getting this error message.

#### Question #2

But, what I really want to do is set up an if/else function because my dataset has variables x1, x2, x3, and x4 and I want to take those variables into account as well.  But when I try something simple such as:

```
j <- function(x) {
  if(x == 1){
    mydf$z <- 0
  } else {
    mydf$z <- mydf$n
  }
  return(mydf)
  }

mydf <- ddply(mydf, x, .fun = j, .inform = TRUE)
```

I get:

```
Warning messages:
1: In if (x == 1) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if (x == 1) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

#### Question #3

I'm confused about to use function() and when to use function(x).  Using function() for either j() or k() gives me a different error:

```
Error in .fun(piece, ...) : unused argument (piece)
Error: with piece 1: 
    n x x1  z
1  12 1  0 12
2   9 1  2  9
3   3 1  1  3
4  12 1  0 12
5   9 1  2  9
6   3 1  1  3
7  12 1  0 12
8   9 1  2  9
9   3 1  1  3
10 12 1  0 12
11  9 1  2  9
12  3 1  1  3
```

where column z is not correct. Yet I see a lot of functions written as function().

I sincerely appreciate any comments that can help me out with this

Comment: @Metrics Both questions involve ddply and ifelse, but in what sense other than that could they be considered duplicates?

Comment: @Joran: other than these two, none :)

Comment: +1 for reproducible example and clear explanation

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's a lot that needs explaining here. Let's start with the simplest case. In your first example, all you need is:

```
mydf$z <- with(mydf,ifelse(x == 1,0,n))
```

An equivalent `ddply` solution might look like this:

```
ddply(mydf,.(x),transform,z = ifelse(x == 1,0,n))
```

Probably your biggest source of confusion is that you seem to not understand what is being passed as arguments to functions within `ddply`.

Consider your first attempt:

```
k <- function(x) {
  mydf$z <- ifelse(x == 1, 0, mydf$n)
  return (mydf)
}
```

The way `ddply` works is that it splits `mydf` up into several, smaller data frame, based on the values in the column `x`. That means that each time `ddply` calls `k`, the argument passed to `k` is *a data frame*. Specifically, a subset of you primary data frame.

So within `k`, `x` is a subset of `mydf`, with all the columns. You should not be trying to modify `mydf` from within `k`. Modify `x`, and then return the modified version. (If you must, but the options I displayed above are better.) So we might re-write your `k` like this:

```
k <- function(x) {
  x$z <- ifelse(x$x == 1, 0, x$n)
  return (x)
}
```

Note that you've created some confusing stuff by using `x` as both an argument to `k` *and* as the name of one of our columns.

Comment: @baptiste I know. That's why my first option just used `ifelse`. But they might as well know how to use `ddply` while we're at it.

Comment: i knew you knew, which you knew I knew; the new version explains more

Comment: @baptiste Sorry, I didn't know that I didn't know that you knew that I knew, you know?

Comment: @joran Thank you very much for your response. Yes, it's not good form for my column to be named x.  Fixing that helped me look at things more clearly.   I needed to write and name a function because I have 5 elses following my if (this example is simplified). Your answer fixed my problem.  I'm re-reading it now because it's such a clear explanation of ddply and arguments/functions.  Thank you for taking the time to write your response.